# Why am I getting "unexpected end of file" with zlib.js?

Tags: node.js, zlib, unzip

I'm using the [unzipper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzipper) Node.js package and it was working fine, processing through my files, when suddenly for seemingly no reason, I got this error:

```
events.js:291
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: unexpected end of file
    at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (zlib.js:180:17)
Emitted 'error' event on Parse instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: -5,
  code: 'Z_BUF_ERROR'
}
```

The error gets thrown every time this particular file is processed, others seem to work fine, but I can't think of what's different about this one.
Is this potentially a user-mistake, or a bug I should report?

code:

```
console.log("unzipping", zipPath) // <-- error triggers after this log
fs.createReadStream(zipPath)
    .pipe(unzipper.Parse())
    .on('entry', function(entry) {
      entry.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(csvPath)).on('finish', () => {
        console.log("done unzipping", zipPath)
        fd = fs.openSync(csvPath, "r+")
        initializeFile()
      })
    })
}
```

Comment: Have you tested that file with a command-line unzip utility to see if its valid?

Comment: @MarkAdler Other zip programs worked. I ended up just going with a different zip node module and everything worked fine, it must be a bug

Comment: What other zip module?